# Expect third party static method call in PHPUnit test

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a custom SimpleSAMLphp module class that I want to test with PHPUnit.

```
class sspmod_wcmccore_Auth_Process_EnforceAuthzPolicy extends sspmod_ldap_Auth_Process_BaseFilter {
  public function __construct($config, $reserved) {

  }

  /**
  * Enforce the authorization policy for the application.
  *
  * @param array &$request The current request
  */
  public function process(&$request) {
    assert('is_array($request)');
    assert('array_key_exists("Attributes", $request)');

    $entityID = $request['core:SP'];

    $config = SimpleSAML_Configuration::getConfig('../authz-policies.php');
    $policies = $config->getValue('policies');
    
    if (array_key_exists($entityID, $policies)) {
      // Perform some checks and set $authorized

      if (!$authorized) {
        $id  = SimpleSAML_Auth_State::saveState($request, 'wcmccore:authz');
        $url = SimpleSAML\Module::getModuleURL('wcmccore/not-authorized.php');
        SimpleSAML_Utilities::redirect($url, array('StateId' => $id));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to mock the `SimpleSAML_Utilities::redirect` call to expect it is called once.

```
final class EnforceAuthzPolicyTest extends TestCase
{
  public function testCallsRedirectWhenNotAuthorized(): void
  {
    $request = array(
      'Attributes' => array(
        'memberOf' => array(),
        'isMemberOf' => array(),
      ),
      'core:SP' => 'box.net'
    );

    $ss_util_mock = $this->createMock(SimpleSAML_Utilities::class);
    $ss_util_mock->expects($this->once())
                 ->method('redirect');

    $eap = new sspmod_wcmccore_Auth_Process_EnforceAuthzPolicy(Null, Null);

    $eap->process($request);
  }
}
```

Right now it seems that `$ss_util_mock` is not being called and I know that https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/test-doubles.html#mock-objects shows the mock being "attached" but I do not know how to do that here without modifying my original class.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with [Mockery](https://github.com/mockery/mockery/).

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\MockeryPHPUnitIntegration;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

require_once('core/lib/Auth/Process/EnforceAuthzPolicy.php');

final class EnforceAuthzPolicyTest extends TestCase {
  // Use the PHPUnit Mockery integration so assertions are added
  use MockeryPHPUnitIntegration;

  public function tearDown(): void {
    \Mockery::close();
  }

  public function testCallsRedirectWhenNotAuthorized(): void {
    $request = array(
      'Attributes' => array(
        'memberOf' => array(),
        'isMemberOf' => array(),
      ),
      'core:SP' => 'box.net'
    );
    
    // Create a SimpleSAML_Utilities mock and expect it to receive ::redirect
    $mock = \Mockery::mock('alias:SimpleSAML_Utilities');
    $mock->shouldReceive('redirect');

    // Create a new instance of the class we are testing 
    // and call the method that we expect to trigger the above static method call.
    $enforcer = new sspmod_wcmccore_Auth_Process_EnforceAuthzPolicy(Null, Null);
    $enforcer->process($request);
  }
}
```